# chrony - local stratum & orphan - when there's no Internet

Tags: ntp, chrony, stratum

Most **chrony server** configurations I've found so far are about commenting out and setting the **allow** directive.

I'd like several servers in my network to be synchronized to one of my 2 dedicated **chrony NTP servers**, even if there's no Internet, and when each **chronyd** is not able to synchronize to any of **X.pl.pool.ntp.org** servers.

According to man, **local stratum** directive allows **chrony** to serve time '*even if not synchronized to a time source*' - I'm wondering if it works in the following way: as long as **chronyd** is able to sync to one of the **X.pl.pool.ntp.org** servers, everything is fine; when **chronyd** is not able to sync to any external source, then it still serves as a valid NTP server for the local clients thanks to **local stratum** directive - am I right? Isn't it like telling the clients that **chrony** is always *healthy* no matter the Internet connection status thus *you can always sync to it*?

**Question 1**: should I comment out **local stratum 10** to meet my requirements?

**Question 2**: I'm also considering using **orphan mode** on my NTP servers in the following way: **local stratum 10 orphan**

As far as I understand, it works in the following way: let's assume my NTP servers lose connections to all X.pl.pool.ntp.org servers (I configured them to pool the same external sources) - now - thanks to **local stratum 10 orphan**, the clients will always sync to the server with the lowest Reference ID first (we assume my production servers are set to poll only my local NTP servers) - am I right about it?

Regards,